# Node.js: Radio streaming Api

Tags: node.js, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I am working on a project in which i have to make Api for radio streaming by which user can listen radio stream from his mobile application **not web**. Please let me know if there is any framework in **Node.js** which can stream my audio file to mobile clients in real time.

I have a look on [Binary.js](http://binaryjs.com/) but I am not sure it can deal with my mobile clients. Anyone please guide me on this.

Comment: Look at this: https://github.com/StreamMachine/StreamMachine

Comment: Questions asking for a 3rd party library are considered off-topic at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [STK-on-iOS](https://github.com/arielelkin/STK-on-iOS)

Simply create an object and pass your Radio streaming URL. I hope it'll help.

in .h file create object

```
STKAudioPlayer*  audioPlayer;
```

In .m file

```
if (isRadioOn == YES)
    {
        [self.audioPlayer pause];
        isRadioOn = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        self.audioPlayer = [[STKAudioPlayer alloc] init];
        [self.audioPlayer play:@"http://Your URL here/;stream.mp3%20&13202692901&duration=99999&id=scplayer&autostart=true"];
        isRadioOn = YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on a project in which i have to make Api for radio streaming by which user can listen radio stream from his mobile application not web.

It makes no difference.  Your mobile app can play HTTP progressive streams just like the web page can.  You can also use HLS.

Don't use web sockets, there is no reason for that complexity and overhead.